# Can't disable font-lock-mode

Tags: debugging, font-lock, themes, performance

If I have font-lock on and I do `M-x find-library RET simple RET`, I have colours:
[image]
If I then `M-x font-lock-mode` to disable the mode, the colours disappear in the currently-visible portion of the buffer:
[image]
But the colours are still present everywhere else if I scroll the buffer:
[image]

This does not happen with `emacs -Q`. Any ideas on how to debug it?

```
GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0, NS appkit-2022.30 Version 11.2.1 (Build 20D75)) of 2021-03-13
```

Update: It happens with a fresh `Doom` emacs, so I am reporting it as an [issue](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/4924).

Answer (score 1):

> Can't disable font-lock-mode ... i have tried `(global-font-lock-mode -1)` and manually disabling `font-lock-mode` locally via `M-x`; The result (for all major modes) is that the visible lines are stripped of color

You have successfully disabled `font-lock-mode`.

> but the other lines in the buffer are still colored.

Sure, but evidentially not via `font-lock-mode`.  There are other ways to apply faces to text.  Such cases will probably be using overlays or text properties.

I suspect your real question is something like "How do I make Emacs use the default face for all text?"

Comment: I don’t care about the colors, I just want the performance boost for large files. Is what I have done enough? And if the colors are done via other overlays, why do the visible lines lose their colors? Setting font-lock-keywords to nil also uncolors almost everything.

Comment: I don't know precisely what your examples are doing (and I don't use flycheck), but clearly *some* of the colouring was via font-lock.  If a performance boost is the goal, then what you've done is probably good -- but performance is subjective, so only you can say for sure.  I generally use `so-long` when I want a performance boost over any other concerns.

Comment: If you still have performance concerns, please ask a separate question about that (as this question has nothing to do with performance, even if that was your goal).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question; Ignoring flycheck, disabling font-lock-mode only uncolors the lines currently visible on the screen, meaning that if I scroll, the other lines are still colored. The flycheck part was just a tangent which on retrospect I should not have included in the question.

Comment: So for a recipe we can all follow... if you have font-lock on and you `M-x find-library RET simple RET` and scroll up and down you have colours; but if you then `M-x font-lock-mode` to disable the mode, the colours disappear in the currently-visible portion of the buffer only, but the colours are still present everywhere else if you scroll the buffer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will change the question's screenshots to this.

Comment: Interesting.  That's not normal.  Does it still happen when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Please also copy/paste the output of `C-u M-x emacs-version` into the question.

Comment: Done. `emacs -Q` acts normally and does not have this bug.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you'll probably have to debug your config to isolate what's causing it.  https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter might be very useful here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957 describes how to do the equivalent manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123420/discussion-between-happyface-and-phils).